# Winscard Dll with WCF

Tags: c#, winscard

My Project structure

```
 myApp 
  -->WCFSerLibrary 
  -->ClassLib1
  -->ClassLib2  // This one uses winscard.dll
```

I wanted to communicate with a Smartcard reaer attached.

Four steps I follow for that are

1. SCardEstablishContext
2. Get the reader name via SCardListReaders
3. SCardConnect
4. Read with SCardTransmit

The first three steps execute succesfully  but when i try to do a SCardTransmit it gives back me response code of **87**.

Second side, The above mentioned scenario is when I call it from WCF service. Now I use the same ClassLib2 in a Windows FOrm application it communicates properly.

```
 retCode =  ModWinsCard.SCardTransmit(hCard, ref pioSendRequest, ref SendBuff[0], sendLen, ref pioSendRequest, ref RecvBuff[0], ref recvLen);
```

where as in  ModWinsCard class

```
   [DllImport("winscard.dll"l)]
    public static extern Int64 SCardTransmit(UInt64 hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, ref byte RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

Comment: It looks like threading issue (and there's no error with 87 code in the list). Could you provide complete piece of code, working with Smart Card Resource Manager? Also, what is myApp? Windows service, IIS application?

Comment: Dennis myApp is a windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

87 is invalid parameter.  The method returns an int not a long.  Also you are passing in only the first item in the in and out buffers. Should use IntPtr for the card handle.

```
LONG WINAPI SCardTransmit(
  _In_         SCARDHANDLE hCard,
  _In_         LPCSCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci,
  _In_         LPCBYTE pbSendBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD cbSendLength,
  _Inout_opt_  LPSCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvPci,
  _Out_        LPBYTE pbRecvBuffer,
  _Inout_      LPDWORD pcbRecvLength
);
```

Maybe try the pinvoke signature below instead?

```
[DllImport("winscard.dll"l)]
        public static extern int SCardTransmit(
            IntPtr hCard, 
            ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest, 
            byte[] SendBuff, 
            int SendBuffLen, 
            ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest, 
            IntPtr RecvBuff,    // Copy with marshal.copy to a managed array after call.
            ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

Comment: Am referencing this link for the same http://chenguo.googlecode.com/svn-history/r262/trunk/DriverTest/DriverTest/ModWinsCard.cs where as long and int . I have changed it to support 64Bit OS

Comment: I am not sure how passing the arrays will work. ref byte the marshaller will just copy the single byte in and copy it out.

Comment: Well you are right the problem was with the handlers have changed Int64 hCard to UIntPtr hCard it worked :) .. Thank u once again :)

Comment: No it is 64Bit- Sorry do I need to change anything ?